# Invalid request, some parameters are invalid or missing using express and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, oauth-2.0

I am struggling to get the access token of the user on LINE oauth2, everything works fine as I can redirect the user to callback URL and generate code in the URL, I've also managed to work it in POSTMAN but in my code, it throws an error

> "Invalid request, some parameters are invalid or missing".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
var queryCode;

app.get("/profile", function (req, res, next) {

  console.log('Request Type:', req.query.code);
  queryCode = req.query.code;
  console.log(typeof queryCode);

  res.render('pages/profile', { code: req.query.code });

  var data = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: queryCode,
    redirect_uri: "https://mydemosampleonlywebsite.com/profile", // not real edited
    client_id: 2, // edited for security
    client_secret: "98" // edited for security
  }

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('body ' + body);
    }else{
      console.log('err ' + body);
    }
  }

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.line.me/oauth2/v2.1/token',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  request.post(options, callback);

  res.end();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solved it using form property instead of body in my options object.

```
 var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.line.me/oauth2/v2.1/token',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    **form: data**
  }
```